# Светлана составляет коды из букв своего имени. Код должен состоять из 8 букв,

Tags: python

Светлана составляет коды из букв своего имени. Код должен состоять из 8 букв, и каждая буква в нём должна встречаться столько же раз, сколько в имени Светлана. Кроме того, одинаковые буквы в коде не должны стоять рядом. Сколько кодов может составить Светлана? ОТВЕТ 15120. ЧТО НЕ ТАК?

```
k=0
for x1 in 'СВЕТЛАНА':
  for x2 in 'СВЕТЛАНА':
    for x3 in 'СВЕТЛАНА':
      for x4 in 'СВЕТЛАНА':
        for x5 in 'СВЕТЛАНА':
          for x6 in 'СВЕТЛАНА':
            for x7 in 'СВЕТЛАНА':
              for x8 in 'СВЕТЛАНА':
                s=x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8
                  if s.count('А') == 2 \
                     and s.count('С') == 1 \
                     and s.count('В') == 1 \
                     and s.count('Е') == 1 \
                     and s.count('Т') == 1 \
                     and s.count('Л') == 1 \
                     and s.count('Н') == 1 \
                     and s.count('АА') == 0:
                    k=k+1
print(k)
```

Comment: код выглядит совсем непитонически, это точно не так:-) Но вас явно что-то другое беспокоит. Что именно - что не так?

Comment: В результате получается 60480

Comment: Ваш код сейчас допускает повторение одинаковых кодов. любой из циклов пробует букву А два раза. А вообще стоит подумать о более красивом алгоритме. Что если вам поставят задачу не с 8 буквами, а скажем с 1000. вы будете писать 1000 вложенных циклов ? Или например по условиям задачи количество букв вообще пользователь будет вводить

Comment: Больше не будет. Это егэ задача

Comment: @Mike, вот только вопрос,  почему пробуя 2 раза А в 8 циклах, увеличение всего лишь в 4 раза:-)

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста)

Comment: @Сергей потому что буквы A стоять рядом не должны. По крайней мере если все циклы сделать СВЕТЛАН то ответ сходится и расходовать память на массив used и поиск перебором в нем (а что еще будет делать in с массивом как не перебирать его) не требуется

Comment: Посмотрите ответ. Там подсказка, как можете увидете сами. Как понимаю я, основная причина в том, что у вас две буквы А. И когда они меняются местами, то система считает что это новая комбинация. Но для нас-то эти буквы равнозначны.

Comment: @Mike, тогда вам просто повезло угадать, думаю:-) Интуиция сильная. Случай двух букв А рядом Анна исключила в `s.count('АА') == 0`, а вот их смену друг с другом - нет.

Comment: @Mike, относительно СВЕТЛАН - такая практическая оптимизация хороша в реальной жизни, но нарушит условия и помешает Анне сдать ЕГЕ. А доп.массив уже ситуацию не сильно ухудшит при выбранном варианте реализации наивным алгоритмом (Анна, на всякий случай: "наивный" - стандартное формальное наименование для простых, но медленных алгоритмов).

Comment: @Сергей Почему СВЕТЛАН нарушит условие задачи ? И если вдруг надо что бы слово СТВЕТЛАНА было целиком никто не мешает писать `for x in set('СВЕТЛАНА')`. И да, интуиция мой конек. но она на логике работает. такие циклы физически не способны сгенерировать повторы, если их нет в перебираемом значении

Comment: @Mike, а как вы, перебирая буквы слова СВЕТЛАН, получите комбинацию с двумя А, что требуется в условии?

Comment: @Сергей Но ведь каждый цикл отвечает за букву в своей позиции кода. пускай у нас будет всего 2 таких цикла. будет такое состояние, когда первый цикл выдаст букву А и второй то же выдаст букву А, и в итоге мы получим АА

Answer (score 3):

Давайте посмотрим задачу с другой стороны. Пусть у нас восемь разных букв. Сколько можно сделать перестановок? `8!`. Теперь из этих восьми букв две одинаковые. Сколько тогда разных перестановок? `8! / 2`, потому что теперь все мы не различаем пары перестановок в которых две одинаковые буквы на одних и тех местах:

> ```
> светланA, светлAна - если мы различаем буквы аА,
>     \        /       это две разные перестановки
>      \      /
>      светлана      - если буквы а неразличимы, перестановка одна
> ```

Сколько перестановок в которых две буквы `а` рядом? Каждая такая перестановка соответствует перестановке из семи различных букв, потому что:

> ```
> светлаан <-> светлан
> ```

Таких перестановок `7!`.

Из числа всех перестановок вычтем плохие:

> ```
> 8! / 2 - 7! = 8 * 7! / 2 - 7! = 3 * 7! =
> = 3 * 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 = 3 * 120 * 6 * 7 = 720 * 21 = 
> = 14400 + 720 = 15120
> ```

Comment: Ах, тыж, хитрец))) +

Answer (score 2):

В комментариях к другому ответу писал, вот что я имею в виду

```py
from itertools import permutations

a = list("светлана")
temp = permutations(a, 8)
b = set(["".join(i) for i in list(temp)])

counter = 0
for i in b:
    if "аа" not in i:
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```

вывод

```py
15120
```

Comment: По сути ваш ответ верен. Я только про код: `list("светлана")` -> `"светлана"`, `list(temp)` -> `temp`, `set([...])` -> `set(...)`. `b = set(...)` -> `b = set(map("".join, permutations("светлана", 8)))`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я в лоб показывал, не мудрствуя лукаво. Ваш ответ на подходе к вычислениям почти все отрезает. Надо было математически мне сначала решить, круто, че)

Comment: Ваш ответ важен, так как показывает универсальный метод решения всего круга таких задач. То что, это конкретный пример можно срезать - случайность.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо, за тыканье меня носом. Разобрал разницу через документацию python между моим кодом и то, что вы говорили. Надо было генератор использовать, а не готовый список   

Answer (score 0):

Анна, вот вам код, исправленный тем же подходом, что и у вас применён.
Исключено повторение последовательностей. Теперь результат 15120.
Подсказка: вы могли сам это обнаружить, упростив пример до слова "AСA", например, и прогнав в отладчике или на бумажке (что я и сделал:-).

```
used=[]
k=0
for x1 in 'СВЕТЛАНА':
  for x2 in 'СВЕТЛАНА':
    for x3 in 'СВЕТЛАНА':
      for x4 in 'СВЕТЛАНА':
        for x5 in 'СВЕТЛАНА':
          for x6 in 'СВЕТЛАНА':
            for x7 in 'СВЕТЛАНА':
              for x8 in 'СВЕТЛАНА':
                s=x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8
                  if s.count('А') == 2 \
                     and s.count('С') == 1 \
                     and s.count('В') == 1 \
                     and s.count('Е') == 1 \
                     and s.count('Т') == 1 \
                     and s.count('Л') == 1 \
                     and s.count('Н') == 1 \
                     and s.count('АА') == 0 \
                     and s not in used:
                    k=k+1
                    used.append(s)  
print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо того, чтобы решать это задание из егэ миллионами циклов, лучше ознакомьтесь с библиотекой itertools https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/529356/. Методов для егэ там - уйма, просто прочитайте статью и потренируйтесь их юзать. Касаемо вашего задания - используйте функцию permutations из модуля itertools. Вот код:

```
from itertools import permutations

count = 0
for variant in permutations("СВЕТЛАНА", 8):
    if "АА" not in "".join(variant):
        count += 1

print(count / 2)
```

Comment: почему вы результат на 2 делите?

Comment: @Dmitry, чтобы ответ правильный получить:-)) Если серьёзно, то смотрите мой комментарий выше - "у нас две буквы А. И когда они меняются местами, то система считает что это новая комбинация. Но для нас-то эти буквы равнозначны. "

Comment: @Сергей не круто, если собрать результат `permutations` в список строк и конвернтнуть в `set`, то уйдет это неведомое действие

Comment: @Dmitry это всё здорово собирать и конвертировать, но скорость set() - O(n)

Comment: @Dmitry, не буду критиковать автора решения. Я `itertools` пока не изучил, так что не знаю, не замедлит ли такой подход его решение.

Comment: @headswillroll ну тогда объясните ваше действие, подгонять под ответ не айс

Comment: @Сергей permutations переставляет, а не перебирает, работает быстрее во много раз

Comment: @Dmitry вам Сергей объяснил. Я ничего не подгонял, вы можете собирать строку и добавлять её в множество. Вот только учитывая, что add в set на таких числах 100% будет O(n + k) - это будет медленнее

Comment: @headswillroll сомневаюсь, что на егэ учитывается сложность алгоритмов, хотя я от школы далек

Comment: @Dmity я как-то решал эту фигню, они теперь ввели маленький файл и большой файл с тестовыми входными - как бы, я не знаю, какие там тайм лимиты

Comment: Анна, если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева). Можно сделать и то, и другое, если понравилось.

Answer (score 0):

Советую использовать библиотеку itertools и её функцию product, так код будет выглядеть намного лучше:

```
from itertools import product


def f(n: str):
    return 'АА' not in n and n.count('А') == 2 \
           and n.count('С') \
           and n.count('В') \
           and n.count('Е') \
           and n.count('Т') \
           and n.count('Л') \
           and n.count('Н')


print(sum(map(lambda x: f("".join(x)), product("СВЕТЛАН", repeat=8))))  # Имя подавать без дубликатов букв
print(sum(map(lambda x: f(''.join(x)), set(permutations("СВЕТЛАНА", r=8))))) # Второй вариант решения
```

Вывод

```
15120
15120
```

Данный код применим к любому имени, главное менять функцию проверки, в зависимости от условия. И само имя поданное в функцию.

Comment: product занимается декартовым произведением, то есть перебирает. лучше использовать permutations. если переставлять, там порядка 40к комбинаций, если перемножать то за 600к, скорее всего

Comment: Я думал об этом, просто в таком случае на permutation надо будет применить set, и здесь я не стал вдаваться что будет лучше по ассимптоматике. Но я добавлю второй вариант, на всякий случай.